# Should I create a PHP file for every SetInterval() that I create?

Tags: javascript, php

I use this JS to call a PHP file in header.php every second.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ $('#show').load('m1.php') }, 1000);
})

<div id="show"></div>
```

In m1, I get data from a database:

```
$getvalue=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM users WHERE user_accID=$user_accID"));
$user_value=$getvalue['user_value'];
echo $user_value;
```

I want to get another data from database for example `user_value30` and call this data with `setinterval` again.

Should I create another m2.php and call it again with same JS?

This way it would be so complex.

Please don't tell me get the all data in m1.php.

I can't because I want to show this data different places in header.php.

Comment: This makes no sense. If the value of `$user_accID` is the only thing which you plan to change then why can't `m1.php` be re-used? How is `$user_accID` being set anyways?

Comment: Well if use m1 again i can't show the user_value30 different place on header.php.Because setinterval create a div#show and it becomes one part.

Comment: Good luck to you

Comment: If I think wrong tell me.

Comment: I did tell you and asked questions but you decided to ignore me. What kind of answer do you expect at this point?

Comment: Sorry english is not my mother tonque.I miss understand you.I thought i answered ur question.If you are asking how user_accID being set i get the data from session

Comment: Don't copy the same script to a new file. Send PARAMETERS to the PHP script.
Like MonkeyZeus said: where does $user_accID come from?

Comment: It comes from m1.php

Comment: Dont use setInterval for Ajax stuff (or don’t use it at all). If the server needs more time than the interval provides your risking DOSssing your own server. Instead, use callbacks/promises.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: If you're thinking about creating a whole bunch of different `.php` files to represent different stages, you may want to think seriously about using a development framework which will give this a lot more structure.

Comment: As already mentioned you can use parameters in the ajax call. Or you **could** get all data in m1, send an object over and render the parts with javascript, whatever is more comfortable. Would all refresh intervals be the same?

Comment: @tadman - c'mon man, don't rob her of the richness that is PDO, giving her the brutally limited mysqli_* stuff instead.

Comment: @enhzflep I'm not advocating for `mysqli` over PDO here, I'm just saying if you're using `mysqli` then using the object-oriented interface is pretty much a must. PDO is a lot better, but I'm not dictating terms, just giving advice.